# Crash Loopback Error: Why do imported DockerHub pods never start in Openshift Origin?

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin

When I try pull in containers from DockerHub, they never start. The pod's status quickly shifts from "pulling container" to "Crash loopback error". The pod's color shifts from light gray to dark gray and then to yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in Openshift. It is a bug that has yet to be fixed. I don't have documentation on the issue, but I was told in the recent Redhat conference in San Francisco. So you'll have to take my word for it.

I have good news and bad news. The good news is that this can be fixed. The bad news is that it isn't a one time fix. You'll have to repeat it each time you import a new container.

OK. So the solution is actually quite simple. You'll just need to delete some things from the deployment config and edit other things.

Firstly locate:

```
triggers:
- type: ConfigChange
- imageChangeParams:
    automatic: true
    containerNames:
    - deployment-example
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: recreate-example:latest
  type: ImageChange
```

Delete this part:

```
- imageChangeParams:
    automatic: true
    containerNames:
    - deployment-example
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: recreate-example:latest
  type: ImageChange
```

Then you'll need to locate something like this

```
dockerImageRepository: 'docker.io/docker/whalesay:sha@234r3esf23k333k532ldfdsfsdfsdf7d68587d5f78'
```

Remove the `:sha@234r3esf23k333k532ldfdsfsdfsdf7d68587d5f78` part.

Openshift will pull the container again. It should start properly now. Like I said before, you'll need to do this for every image pulled from DockerHub.

Comment: Hmmm, there may be more than one way of doing it then as I don't use the same method. The ``ImageChange`` trigger does need to be removed, but as I understand it, rather than edit the ``dockerImageRepository`` reference in the ``ImageStream``. my understanding is that it is ``dc.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image`` that would need to be changed to use reference the image from the remote registry explicitly, such as like ``docker.io/docker/whalesay:latest``.